# Drop DB on AWS RDS instance - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Trying to drop a db from AWS RDS (postgres) is blocked only for superuser (which is reserved to AWS only).

trying to run this command on my instance:

```
DROP DATABASE "dbname"
```

results in error:

```
psycopg2.InternalError: DROP DATABASE cannot run inside a transaction block
```

I saw [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=66637) issue in AWS forums, which seems to have been active by a lot of people, but no AWS representative giving a valid solution.

How can I drop my db without taking down the whole instance and raising it again?

Comment: How did you end up doing?

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres I'm not exactly sure as this was a long time ago, but the premise is to connect to a different db (you must be connected to a db to execute any query) and execute the DROP from there. I think you can do it from the default "postgres" db (every postgres has it). Please update if you managed.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres, after a short read, maybe you can try executing `psql -l` on your server (directly on the postgres server, not as a query). This will give you a list of all databases available on that server. Then choose a db that is not the one you want to drop and run `\connect <DB_NAME>`, which will connect you to that db. There you should be able to run the DROP DB commnad

Answer (score 5):

Worked for me:

1. Connect to **postgres** DB, disconnect from DB you want to DROP!
2. `select pg_terminate_backend(pid) from pg_stat_activity where datname='yourdb';`
3. `drop database 'yourdb';`

Step 2 and 3 execute fast in order to prevent user **rdsadmin** reconnect

Comment: If you only have one DB in step 1, try `create database tmpdb;` then `\c tmpdb`

Answer (score 0):

Try using [ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/extensions.html#psycopg2.extensions.ISOLATION_LEVEL_AUTOCOMMIT), a psycopg2 extensions:

> No transaction is started when command are issued and no commit() or
>   rollback() is required.

The connection must be in autocommit mode. You can way can set it using psycopg2 is through the autocommit attribute:

```
import psycopg2

con = psycopg2.connect(...)
con.autocommit = True

cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute('DROP DATABASE db;')
```

Comment: this gives me the same error. I think that AWS is wrapping it in a transaction, and not psycopg. I can also prove it by the fact that im able to drop the db locally (on a postgres container) with the same command

Comment: Have you tried this  PSQL command from a connected session? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/ecpg-sql-set-autocommit.html Try to set autocommit Off as shown. Then rerun the drop.

Comment: I did try that. Same error. this is so frustrating. I dont have control over my db